# Command StdinPipe closes too soon

Tags: postgresql, go, command-line, pipe

I've been trying to call `pg_restore` using `exec.Command` and feed `StdinPipe` with data from database dump file, it works with small files under 1Mb but it fails for bigger dumps with the  `write |1: broken pipe` error. I also tried to scan line by line and write to pipe but it resulted in the same error and running like `cmd.Run()` in separate goroutine didn't help either.

Go: 1.14
OS: macOS

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("pg_restore", "--clean", "-n public", "--dbname=DB_URI")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
pw, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
defer pw.Close()
...

done := make(chan struct{})
errCh := make(chan error)
file, err := os.Open("dumpfile")
defer file.Close()

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = io.Copy(pw, file)
```

What am I doing wrong or how to keep pipe open?

Comment: Did you try to use `cmd.Wait()` after `io.Copy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my colleague we found that command arguments were malformed, since Go directly uses syscalls each argument of a program must be separate so here
`-n public` was leading to the issue

`"pg_restore", "--clean", "-n public", "--dbname=DB_URI"`

and the fix quite clear as well – split them `-n`, `public`

`"pg_restore", "--clean", "-n", "public", "--dbname=DB_URI"`

Answer (score 0):

When using `cat` instead of `pg_restore`, your code works.
When using `head -10`, on the other hand, I hit the same error as you, which is actually expected.

Since you are starting your `cmd` in async mode, if `pg_restore` halts before consuming all of its `STDIN`, `io.Copy` will hit this kind of error if it tries to write on a closed pipe.

Check the state of your `pg_restore` command (final return code, content printed on its STDERR, logs ...) to see if there is an actual error.

You can treat this error as a normal indication that you shouldn't feed input to this command anymore.

Comment: Thanks for response, yes I completely agree about the point you make. The question is how to keep stdinpipe open?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to keep that pipe open ? or is it just to avoid the error returned by io.Copy ?

Comment: Short answer is : if the cause of the error is that the `pg_restore` process is no longer there, you can't -- you can't keep a pipe to a non existing process open.

Comment: While it works well with small files I've been piping to command but large database dumps cause this so I was wondering if it is possible to keep it open. When running the same command from console it works as expected.

Comment: @sultan : in your go code, have you checked the exit status of your command ? does anything get printed on Stdout or Stderr ?

Comment: only the message about broken pipe is there but stderr is empty.

Comment: The issue lies somewhere else. How do you wait for the command to complete ?

Comment: side note : if your intention is to feed `file` to your process, you can set `cmd.Stdin = file`

Answer (score 0):

including `cmd.Wait()` should solve your problem, like it says int one of your comments.